# Eslint fix command is not fixing all of the vue/html-indent errors

Tags: html, css, vue.js, eslint, vetur

I have some linting rules in my `.eslintrc.js` which looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/recommended', 'eslint:recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
  rules: {
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'import/no-unresolved': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'no-shadow': 0, // TODO: figure out this error in vuex state
    'no-param-reassign': 0, // TODO: figure out this error in vuex state
    'no-use-before-define': 0, // TODO: figure out this error in vuex state
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'no-useless-escape': 0,
    semi: [2, 'never'],
    'vue/no-v-html': 0,
    'vue/custom-event-name-casing': 0,
    'vue/html-indent': [
      'error',
      4,
      {
        attribute: 1,
        baseIndent: 1,
        closeBracket: 0,
        alignAttributesVertically: true,
        ignores: [],
      },
    ],
    'vue/script-indent': [
      'error',
      2,
      {
        baseIndent: 1,
        switchCase: 1,
        ignores: [],
      },
    ],
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: 1,
        multiline: {
          max: 1,
          allowFirstLine: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': [
      'error',
      {
        singleline: 'never',
        multiline: 'never',
      },
    ],
    'vue/html-self-closing': [
      'error',
      {
        html: {
          void: 'always',
          normal: 'always',
          component: 'always',
        },
        svg: 'always',
        math: 'always',
      },
    ],
    'vue/attribute-hyphenation': ['error', 'always'],
  },
}
```

I have these setup as my workspace settings:

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 4,
  "editor.insertSpaces": false,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "vetur.format.options.useTabs": false,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "prettyhtml": {
      "printWidth": 120,
      "singleQuote": true
    },
    "js-beautify-html": {
      "wrap_attributes": "force-aligned",
      "indent_size": 4
    }
  },
  "vetur.format.scriptInitialIndent": true,
  "vetur.format.styleInitialIndent": true,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier-eslint",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css": "none",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.scss": "prettier",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "vetur.validation.template": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```

When I save a file and format everything works fine, the formatting works. But when I run

```
eslint --fix --ext js,vue src
```

This shows the lint warnings and errors, but doesn't comply with the `vue/html-indent` rule.

1. If the component looks like this:

```
<transition
        name="slide-fade"
        mode="in-out">
        <div
            v-if="showDesktopSearch"
            v-on-clickaway="away"
            class="desktop-search-component"
            :class="positionClass">
            This is the body
        </div>
</transition>
```

2. If I save the component looks like this:

```
<transition name="slide-fade"
                mode="in-out">
        <div v-if="showDesktopSearch"
             v-on-clickaway="away"
             class="desktop-search-component"
             :class="positionClass">
             This is the body
        </div>
</transition>
```

3. But if I run the linting command, it looks like this:

```
<transition
        name="slide-fade"
        mode="in-out">
        <div
            v-if="showDesktopSearch"
            v-on-clickaway="away"
            class="desktop-search-component"
            :class="positionClass">
            This is the body
        </div>
</transition>
```

I want to fix all of the `vue/html-indent` errors when running the lint command, but I have been unsuccessful here. How can I get the vetur/eslint format from cli?

Comment: Hi have you found the solution, i'm running in similar issue

Answer (score -1):

This is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    browser: true,
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', 'plugin:prettier/recommended', '@vue/prettier'],
  rules: {
    'eqeqeq': 'off',
    'no-plusplus': 'off',
    "no-return-assign": "off",
    'max-len': ['error', { code: 120, ignoreUrls: true, ignoreComments: true }],
    'linebreak-style': 0,
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 'off',
    'vue/component-name-in-template-casing': ['error', 'PascalCase'],
    'no-console': 'off',
    'no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      {
        selector:
          "CallExpression[callee.object.name='console'][callee.property.name!=/^(log|warn|error|info|trace)$/]",
        message: 'Unexpected property on console object was called',
      },
    ],
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
};
```

And `.prettierrc`

```
{
  "semi": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 100,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "arrowParens": "always"
}
```

And `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3201,
    https: false,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  runtimeCompiler: true,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('eslint')
      .use('eslint-loader')
      .options({
        fix: true,
      });
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    apollo: {
      enableMocks: true,
      enableEngine: false,
      // Cross-Origin options
      cors: '*',
    },
  },
};
```